# Python: I cannot send an email, whatever I try

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, gmail

So I tried to send E-Mails via Python from on of my E-Mail Accounts to another, and no matter what i try, i get different Error messages, and googling them won't help me. All suggested fixes don't work for me and im just exhausted. I tried it on GMail and on web.de, both doesnt work.

**Error messages (depend on encrpyption (tls/ssl) or provider (web.de/gmail)):**

Username and Password not accepted.

Transaction failed Unauthorized sender address.

SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

**My Code in a nutshell:**

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.web.de', port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, reciever, message)
```

Comment: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER is **typically** when you attempt to do TLS towards something that is not TLS enabled. Did you ask your providers if you can connect over TLS with them? Did you ask them about your errors?

Comment: At first thank you for your response, but i fixed it on my own. I outcoded the server.login() command and then it worked, so tried to change the content in it and the problem was the Formatting of the sended Text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the correct ssl.SSLContext for your server.
For example:
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
or
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2)

https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/ssl.html

Comment: I now tried all the different Protocols available in ssl, but none of them works, i still get the Error: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)

Comment: SSLv2 ????? You certainly shouldn't do that! Did you mean `SSLv23` instead, that has (unfortunately) a completely different meaning (it means auto negotiating the highest possible protocol value, so hopefully TLS 1.3 or 1.2 in fact)

Comment: At first thank you for your response, but i fixed it on my own. I outcoded the server.login() command and then it worked, so tried to change the content in it and the problem was the Formatting of the sended Text.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.web.de', port, context=context) as server:
> ```

It is unclear which port you are using but you like you the wrong one or you should not use `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`. `SMTP_SSL` is for connections where TLS is spoken from start (implicit TLS). This is true for port 465 (smtps).

`smtp.web.de` does not offer access with port 465 in the first place. This means that underlying TCP connection would already fail which would result in a different error.

Therefore it is likely that you've used port 25 (smtp) or port 587 (submission). Both of these ports require **explicit** TLS though, i.e. they start with a plain connection and upgrade to TLS only after an explicit `STARTTLS` command. For these ports the code should look something like this instead:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
port = 587
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.web.de', port) as server:
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login(sender, password)
    ...
```

Connecting with implicit TLS to a port which does not use implicit TLS can result in very strange error messages since the TLS stack tries to interpret the response from the server as TLS even though it is not TLS (in this case the plain welcome message from the SMTP server, i.e. `220 ... Service ready`). Thus the WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER you see does not actually indicate the wrong version of the response but only that it tried to interpret a specific part of the plain response as the TLS version number and got unexpected results from this.

Comment: At first thank you for your response, but i fixed it on my own. I outcoded the server.login() command and then it worked, so I tried to change the content in it and the problem was the Formatting of the sended Text.